# implem is not abstract and does not override abstract method FinalScore() in extending interfaces

Tags: java, interface, extend

program 1

```
interface java{
    public void setHomeTeam(String name);
    public void setVisitingTeam(String name);
}
```

program 2

```
interface extension extends java {
    public String HomeTeamScored();
    public String VisitingTeamScored();
    public String FinalScore();
}
```

program 3

```
public class implem implements extension{
    private String Home;
    private String Visit;

    public String HomeTeamScored(){
        return Home;
    }

    public String VisitingTeamScored(){
        return Visit;
    }

    public void setHome(String Home){
        this.Home = Home;
    }

    public void setVisit(String Visit){
        this.Visit = Visit;
    }
}
```

program 4

```
public class compilation{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        implem implement = new implem();

        implement.setHome("Nihon");
        implement.setVisit("Chuugoku");

        System.out.println(""+implement.HomeTeamScored());
        System.out.println(""+implement.VisitingTeamScored());
    }
}
```

These are my programs for extending interfaces and I get the error:

> implem is not abstract and does not override abstract method FinalScore() in extension
>   public class implem implements extension{
>          ^
>   1 error
>
> Process completed.

Comment: What's not clear about the error message you got? Implement `FinalScore()`

Comment: Error is clear, you haven't overloaded `FinalScore()` in your `implem` class. So override it, and your program would work.

Comment: and please follow java naming conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a definition of a java's interface[[site]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

It says

> If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined
>   by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will
>   successfully compile

So, your implem class must implement all interface methods from java and its child class extension.

Your implem class have to follow the rule so it looks like as follows,

```
public class implem implements extension {
    private String Home;
    private String Visit;

    @Override
    public String HomeTeamScored() {
        return Home;
    }

    @Override
    public String VisitingTeamScored() {
        return Visit;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHomeTeam(String name) {

    }

    public void setHome(String Home) {
        this.Home = Home;
    }

    public void setVisit(String Visit) {
        this.Visit = Visit;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisitingTeam(String name) {

    }

    @Override
    public String FinalScore() {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. but why can't the `public void setHome(String Home)` and the `public void setVisit(String Visit)` be on the last part I mean after the last `@Override`?

Comment: Not a special meaning..you can do it with any order , if i understand what you mean correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are implementing 'extension' you need to implement all the methods in the interface you need to add

```
Public String FinalScore();
```

To your class

Comment: No you need to add a method that matches the signature of `Public String FinalScore();` - but I understand what you mean

Comment: `public class implem implements extension{
 private String Home;
 private String Visit;
 private String Final;
 
 public String HomeTeamScored(){
  return Home;
 }
 
 public String VisitingTeamScored(){
  return Visit;
 }
 public String FinalScore(){
  return Final;
 }
 
 public void setHome(String Home){
  this.Home = Home;
 }
 public void setVisit(String Visit){
  this.Visit = Visit;
 }}`

now I get implem is not abstract and does not override abstract method setVisitingTeam(String) in java 

sorry I'm pretty new here

Answer (score 0):

Your non-abstract class  **implem** is not implementing all the methods of interfaces. `Public String FinalScore()` is such one method.

Comment: `public class implem implements extension{
 private String Home;
 private String Visit;
 private String Final;
 
 public String HomeTeamScored(){
  return Home;
 }
 
 public String VisitingTeamScored(){
  return Visit;
 }
 public String FinalScore(){
  return Final;
 }
 
 public void setHome(String Home){
  this.Home = Home;
 }
 public void setVisit(String Visit){
  this.Visit = Visit;
 }}`

now I get implem is not abstract and does not override abstract method setVisitingTeam(String) in java 

sorry I'm pretty new here